# Function won't send Redux Dispatch after a Fetch Delete Request in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch, redux-thunk

I submit a delete request to my backend onClick and when I get the response from the server, I try to call a dispatch function to update the Redux store. The backend data can delete the request effectively; however, when I include the dispatch call, React gives me this error:

```
  ./src/actions/questions.js
  Line 68:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
```

I've tried tons of different syntax and .then combinations after response is received but nothing works. This is confusing to me because in the thunk fetch calls I make, I'm able to call dispatch when I get the response. I'm not able to use the traditional thunk syntax because it won't fire the request since it initially is trigged in an onClick event in a component. So, the delete fetch request I am making looks like this:

```
 export function deleteQuestion(questionId, routerHistory) {
     return fetch(`${API_URL}/questions/${questionId}`, {
         method: 'DELETE',
     }).then(res => 
     dispatch(removeQuestion(questionId)))
   }
```

I've thought about just dispatching removeQuestion outside of the method, but then I worry that the Redux store would become out of sync with the backend data and cause problems later. I'd greatly appreciate any insight anyone could provide. I do not think deleting an item and updating the Redux store should be so challenging.

This is the github as well: https://github.com/jwolfe890/react_project1/blob/master/stumped-app-client/src/actions/questions.js

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off. A thunk will return a function that takes in `dispatch` as a parameter. `dispatch` will be passed in by the middleware. Therefore your action creator should be as follows:

```
export function deleteQuestion(questionId, routerHistory) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`${API_URL}/questions/${questionId}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    }).then(res => {
      dispatch(removeQuestion(questionId))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach initially, but in an onClick handler it gives me issues. To even get the fetch call to run I have to include the following in the onClick method:

Comment: handleDelete = () => {
    const { questionId } = this.props.match.params
    const { history } = this.props
    deleteQuestion(questionId, history)(deleteQuestion);
  }

Comment: Basically, calling the method twice. And on the second call the dispatch function won't run.

Comment: This is your actual issue. You should add this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

See the problem is in your `deleteQuestion` function, neither you have defined what `dispatch` is nor you have passed the `dispatch` as argument to your function. So you are getting the error `dispatch is not defined`.

In `redux-thunk` you return a function which takes `dispatch` as argument which is provided by the `redux-thunk` middleware. And that's why it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: but the deleteQuestion function is exported into a component and called with parameters from that component, so i'm not able to pass the dispatch in as an argument i don't think. and since the deleteQuestion dispatch fires through an onClick event, it doesn't seem possible to define/return dispatch the traditional thunk way.

Comment: This might help you.

http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html.